# Umbraco: x.GetPropertyValue("myProp") vs x.myProp

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco4

I use Umbraco v4, but think this should be a common problem.

I have a generic property "myNode" of "Content Picker", that should obtain a DynamicNode...

so **doying `myObj.myNode` I obtain the node *itself***...  so can use `myObj.myNode.Url`

But **doying the `myObj.GetPropertyValue("myNode")` I obtain the ... string ID** value of the node... so can't anymore do `myObj.GetPropertyValue("myNode").Url` (string does not have `Url` property)

I can't use directly myObj.myNode, because the name is "dynamic" (the same function should use "your"+"Node" or "their"+"Node" upon conditions - the example is very aproximative, but hope the idea is clear)...

I even did `myObj.GetPropertyValue<DynamicNode>("myNode")`, but the result was the same: "8124" (the node id)

So, how to obtain the real property value, not just string representation of it?

Comment: How is myObj instantiated - show us the code? That's not how a content picker works.  Could be some other funky datatype but not a content picker..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A not so elegant solution, but at least a solution that work:

```
var linkNode = image.GetPropertyValue("imgLinkNode" + model._lang.ToUpper());
if (linkNode is string)
{
    string id = linkNode;
    linkNode = model.NodeById(id);
}
var linkNodeUrl = linkNode.Url;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your content picker does not contain a node, it contains an id of a node.

myObj.GetPropertyValue("myNode") does exactly what is says, gets the value of a property called myNode on the instantiated DynamicNode object.  It is not designed to return the node itself.

If you want to return the node whose ID your 'myNode' property contains then you have to use that value in a call to instantiate another DynamicNode

```
DynamicNode myNewNode = new DynamicNode(myObj.GetPropertyValue("myNode"))
```

or

```
Model.NodeById(myObj.GetPropertyValue("myNode"))
```

Comment: I've highlighted the concerned info in the OP... bc your first phrase is not exact.

Answer (score 0):

Use somethings like: `mynode = Umbraco.Content(CurrentPage.myNode).Url` (for Umbraco 6 and 7) For Umbraco 4 i use this  `Model.NodeById(Model.myNode).Url;` in a script file. (I think it need at least Umbraco 4.7.x)

See also https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Backoffice-Overview/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors/Content-Picker

Comment: Umbraco.Content and CurrentPage only apply to U6 +

Comment: the problem is obtaining the node itself, not the Url... , I work with a property of my model node, that property specifies another node... I don't need to work with current model node...

Comment: See my answer below it will do what you need

Comment: Also which version 4 are you on?